# How to write a regular express to replace multi occurence of some string?

Tags: regex, replace

I have a string

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_BAR,ROLE_FOO,ROLE_USER">
```

I want to change it to

```
 <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_BAR','ROLE_FOO','ROLE_USER')">
```

Note that the roles count can be very from one to several.

I can use `<sec:authorize\s+ifAnyGranted="(\w+)"\s*>` to search if there is only one role, e.g. `<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_USER">`.

Certainly if there are two, I can write it as `<sec:authorize\s+ifAnyGranted="(\w+),(\w+)"\s*>` and replace the found strings use `<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('$1','$2')">`.

But how can I replace all those pattern in one trace? Is it possible?

Comment: Do not manipulate XML (or any other structured language) with regexp.

Comment: You are right, any change must tested and reviewed!